# Whose routing table does "route print" display

Tags: routing

When I run `route print` on my windows machine's command prompt, which device's IPv4 routing table is being displayed? Is it the table of the router that my computer is connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's actually the computer's own routing table. The OS sends packets using more or less the same logic as a router does.

(Many, such as Linux or BSD – or even Windows – can have packet forwarding enabled, turning them into actual routers.)